# Redirecting printf and cout to socket

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, printf

I am thinking if it is possible to redirect printf or cout to a socket easily?

I am currently programming in Windows VC++ btw...

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can use the `sprintf` family of functions:

```
// Make sure this buffer is big enough; if the maximum size isn't known, use
// _vscprintf or a dynamically allocated buffer if you want to avoid truncation
char buffer[2048];
_snprintf_s(buffer, sizeof(buffer), _TRUNCATE, "format %s etc.", args...);
send(mySocket, buffer, strlen(buffer)+1, 0);  // +1 for NUL terminator
```

Note that `_snprintf_s` is a Microsoft runtime-only function, so if you're writing portable code, use `snprintf` instead on other platforms.

In C++, you can also use a `std::ostringstream` for similar results:

```
std::ostringstream buffer;
buffer << "test: " << myvar << somethingelse << etc;
send(mySocket, buffer.str().c_str(), buffer.str().size() + 1, 0);
                                                     // +1 for NUL terminator
```

Comment: @PauloBu what about using `dprintf` directly? Would it work?

Answer (score 2):

Linux has dprintf() which allows you to write to a socket file descriptor.

`int dprintf(int fd, const char *format, ...);`

http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_dprintf.htm

Answer (score 1):

Not trivially.  In WinSock (MS Windows) world sockets are not the same as file descriptors.